# How to find the index of a repeated item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a component that draws a repeated component repeatedly from an array, with `map`. The inner component has a delete button for each item. I need the **outer** component to handle the delete, but I can't seem to find a way to get the index of the item to delete. I tried `event.target.value` (which gave me the HTML) and the `key` of the item, but I can't access it.

Outer:

```
const menu = currentBot.items.map((item, i) => (
  <PersistentMenuItem
    key={i}
    ...
    deleteItem={this.deletePersistentMenuItem}
  />
))
```

Inner

```
<IconButton onClick={()=>{this.props.deleteItem( ??? )}}>
    <DeleteIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: can you just pass the id/ key on the props to the child. then return it in callback to parent ```deleteItem(props.id)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this is to pass the index of the element which is supposed to be deleted, something like this:

```
deleteItem={() => this.deletePersistentMenuItem(i)}
```

There's nothing special to do in the inner component.